# How to understand if a customer mac is retina display?

Tags: mac, display

A customer of mine is not able to say if she owns a Retina Display. She sent this info:

```
15-inch (1680 x 1050)
NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 256 MB graphics
```

Can I understand from it, if she owns a retina display?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only Model that came with the following graphics card: NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M 256 MB graphics were the Mid-2010 Macbook Pro's (Non-Retina):

"Core i5" 2.4 15" (Mid-2010)

- 256 MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M
- 256 MB Intel HD Graphics*

"Core i5" 2.53 15" (Mid-2010)

- 256 MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M
- 256 MB Intel HD Graphics*

"Core i7" 2.66 15" (Mid-2010)

- 512 MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M
- 256 MB Intel HD Graphics*

"Core i5" 2.53 17" (Mid-2010)

- 512 MB NVIDIA GeForce GT 330M
- 256 MB Intel HD Graphics*

You can check the following link for a complete list: http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/macbook-pro-unibody-faq/macbook-pro-unibody-video-processor-types-nvidia-dedicated-integrated.html

Answer (score 0):

Ask her for a screenshot (command-shift-3 or 4). If it's massive, she's got Retina.

Comment: This is a workaround maybe, not what he's directly asking for.

Answer (score -1):

From apple website:

> When you pack so many pixels into a display — over 4 million on the 13‑inch model and over 5 million on the 15‑inch model — the results are positively stunning. The pixel density is so high, your eyes can’t discern individual pixels. Images take on a new level of realism. A spectacular 2560-by-1600 resolution on the 13‑inch MacBook Pro and an equally impressive ***2880-by-1800 resolution on the*** **15‑inch MacBook Pro** let you see more of your high-resolution images with pixel-for-pixel accuracy. And text is so sharp, you’ll feel like you’re reading email, web pages, and documents on a printed page.
>   [MacBook Pro with Retina Display - Features](https://www.apple.com/macbook-pro/features-retina/)

but i'd dig more if i want to be sure and ask for model number.

Comment: You mean a number engraved on the mac surface? And how do I know this is a model number with/without retina?

Comment: click Apple logo on the top left > About this Mac < More Info... > and you will get model number ex: iMac 27-inch, Mid 2010